# MPI code returns invalid subcommunicator after MPI_Comm_split

Tags: fortran, mpi

I'm in Fortran and I am learning about MPI. Specifically, I am using 4 processes, and I want to send a message only to ranks 0,1,2 from rank 0 by creating a subcommunicator, to get some practice in their usage. Whatever I try I don't get the desired result that the message is shared.

Here is what I tried.

```
  SUBROUTINE FOO(IER)

  USE MPI
  
  INTEGER    :: IER

  integer :: ierr, rank, size, color
  integer :: subcomm
  integer :: msg

  call MPI_Init(ierr)
  call MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, rank, ierr)
  call MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, size, ierr)
  
  color = MPI_UNDEFINED
  msg = -1
  ! Split the original communicator into two subcommunicators based on rank
  if (rank < 3) then
     color = 0 ! First subcomm has color 0
  end if
  if (rank == 0) then
     msg = 100
  endif

  ! Create the subcommunicator
  call MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, color, rank, subcomm, ierr)
  
  if (rank < 3) then 
     ! Broadcast the message within each subcomm
     call MPI_Bcast(msg, 1, MPI_INTEGER, 0, subcomm, ierr)

     ! Print the result on each process
     print *, 'Process ', rank, ' of ', size, ' in subcomm received msg = ', msg
  endif

  ! Free the subcommunicator and finalize MPI
  call MPI_Comm_free(subcomm, ierr)
  call MPI_Finalize(ierr)

  END SUBROUTINE
```

The function FOO is called by the main program:

```
  PROGRAM DUMMY

  IMPLICIT NONE
  
  INTEGER          IER
  
  CALL FOO(IER)
  
  END PROGRAM DUMMY
```

The output;

```
Process 0  of 4  in subcomm received msg = 100
Process 2 of 4  in subcomm received msg = -1
Process 1  of 4  in subcomm received msg = -1
```

subcomm always amounts to 0 by the way.

Comment: At exactly *which* line do you get "invalid communicator"? Which MPI routine throws the error? MPI_Comm_free?

Comment: @IanBush Let me specify the error in the post

Comment: Do you have `Implicit none` in scope? please show a full program! At one point you are using `rank`, at another `myrank`

Comment: @IanBush sure, will do now

Comment: @IanBush I have provided more details, hopefully it is now clear.

Comment: Apparently MYRANK was always 0 and I managed to find a workaround. Now I get something different.

Comment: **ALWAYS** use `Implicit none`. No more help until you fix that.

Comment: @IanBush Done, subcomm is always zero by the way

Comment: As the subroutine is external, you need `implicit none` also in the subroutine.

Comment: You still haven't put `implicit none` in the subroutine.

Comment: Have you considered testing the return code of the `Comm_split`? Also: try to find a modern compiler that has the `mpi_f08` module. That's much nicer than what you have now. For instance: no `integer :: subcomm` but `type(mpi_comm) :: subcomm`.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout The problem is that such compiler and MPI library versions must be available in every old cluster with some Enterprise Linux (or CentoOS) installation where your users will use the parallel code. That is still quite prohibitive for production.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
call MPI_Comm_free(subcomm, ierr)
```

gives an error on the processes where the subcommunicator is null. Put the same conditional on that line as you put on the split call and the bcast. And next time please include the error message.